# XSL: Comparing nodes by comparing their child nodes

Tags: xslt, xslt-1.0

I would like to be able to compare two nodes based on the values of their child nodes. Testing node equality with the `=` operator just compares the string values of the respective nodes. I would like to compare them based on values in their child nodes.

To be a bit more specific, I would like `<a>` and `<b>` (below) to be equal, because the values of `@id` are the same for `<c>` elements that have matching `@type` attributes also have matching `@id` attributes.

```
<a>
    <c type="type-one" id="5675"/>
    <c type="type-two" id="3423"/>
    <c type="type-three" id="9088"/>
</a>
<b>
    <c type="type-one" id="5675"/>
    <c type="type-two" id="3423"/>
</b>
```

But these would be different:

```
<a>
    <c type="type-one" id="5675"/>
</a>
<b>
    <c type="type-one" id="2342"/>
</b>
```

The only solution I can begin to see involves a laborious comparison with a `for-each` statement, which I would like to avoid if possible.

If possible I would like to stick with XSLT 1.0. I am using xsltproc.

Comment: How can `a` and `b` in the first example be "equal" when `a` has a child element `<c type="type-three" id="9088"/>` that doesn't have a corresponding child of `b` ??? Please, edit the question and correct. The current example contradicts the notion of "equal".

Comment: There isn't a single definition of equality... for instance, nodes with identical inner text are equal in one sense, but that's not the difference I'm interested in. Or in real life, perhaps two people have equal reputation in Stack Overflow, but unequal salaries, etc. etc. etc. ...

Comment: user1447002, Equality is strictly defined as an equivalence relation -- If ~ is equality, it must be 1. Reflexive, 2. Symmetric and 3. Transitive. You have none of these -- and you haven't defined at all the properties of the relation you are calling "equality".

Comment: user1447002, And your "equality is definitely *not* transitive.

Comment: How is my definition either not reflexive, symmetric, or transitive? A "equals" B if all attribute values match for the intersection of A/@* and B/@*. That seems to be reflexive, symmetric, and transitive to me.

Comment: It isn't transitive. It is easy to construct example where a "equals" b and b "equals" c, but a doesn't "equal" c. Left as an exercise to the reader :)

Comment: user1447002, But anyway, I am calling this relation just "matches" and with this in mind I have answered your question.

Comment: I think the example you're looking for is `<a><item key="one" value="foo"/><item key="two" value="one"/></a>, <b><item key="one" value="foo"/><item key="three" value="bar"/></b>, <c><item key="one" value="foo"/><item key="two" value="other"/></c>`, A 'equals' B, B 'equals' C, but A 'does not equal' C. I will expect a fine from the formal logic police. :-)

Comment: user1447002, Also expect a fine from the shortness police -- no extension functions are needed and the solution can be much simpler -- as shown in my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**First of all, the relation called "equals" cannot have that name**.

"Equals" means that the relation is an equivalence relation. By definition any equivalence relation `~` must be:

1. Reflexive: `x ~ x` .
2. Symmetric: if `x ~ y` then `y ~ x`
3. Transitive: if `x ~ y` and `y ~ z` then `x ~ z` .

**Here is an example, showing that the proposed "equals" relation isn't transitive:**

`x` is:

```
<a>
    <c type="type-one" id="5675"/>
    <c type="type-two" id="3423"/>
    <c type="type-three" id="9088"/>
</a>
```

`y` is:

```
<b>
    <c type="type-one" id="5675"/>
    <c type="type-two" id="3423"/>
    <c type="type-four" id="1234"/>
</b>
```

`z` is:

```
<b>
    <c type="type-three" id="3333"/>
    <c type="type-four" id="1234"/>
</b>
```

Now, we can see that `x ~ y` and `y ~ z`. However, clearly this doesn't hold: `x ~ z`

This said, I am calling the relation "matches" and it is relaxed and not "equals".

**Here is a solution to the problem, with the above adjustment**:

**Do note that this cannot be expressed with a single XPath expression, because XPath 1.0 (used within an XSLT 1.0 transformation) doesn't have range variables**.

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

 <xsl:template match="/*">
     <xsl:call-template name="matches">
       <xsl:with-param name="pElem1" select="a"/>
       <xsl:with-param name="pElem2" select="b"/>
     </xsl:call-template>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template name="matches">
   <xsl:param name="pElem1" select="/.."/>
   <xsl:param name="pElem2" select="/.."/>

   <xsl:variable name="vMisMatch">
       <xsl:for-each select="$pElem1/c[@type = $pElem2/c/@type]">
        <xsl:if test=
           "$pElem2/c[@type = current()/@type and not(@id = current()/@id)]">1</xsl:if>
       </xsl:for-each>
   </xsl:variable>

   <xsl:copy-of select="not(string($vMisMatch))"/>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**When this transformation is applied on the following XML document:**

```
<t>
    <a>
        <c type="type-one" id="5675"/>
        <c type="type-two" id="3423"/>
        <c type="type-three" id="9088"/>
    </a>
    <b>
        <c type="type-one" id="5675"/>
        <c type="type-two" id="3423"/>
    </b>
</t>
```

**the wanted, correct result is produced:**

```
true
```

**When the same transformation is applied on this XML document:**

```
<t>
    <a>
        <c type="type-one" id="5675"/>
        <c type="type-two" id="3423"/>
        <c type="type-three" id="9088"/>
    </a>
    <b>
        <c type="type-one" id="5675"/>
        <c type="type-two" id="9876"/>
    </b>
</t>
```

**again the correct result is produced:**

```
false
```

Comment: nice answer! Could you also check [my question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39344435/xslt-transform-nodes-by-comparing-their-child-nodes) ? I'd really appreciate to find out more about how that could be achieved!

Comment: @Dex'ter, I see that your question has been answered (while I was sleeping). Do you need additional help on that?

Comment: if you have something to add to that answer any additional information would be great :) Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I came up with. Given a toy data set like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root>
    <a>
        <item key="x" value="123"/>
        <item key="y" value="456"/>
        <item key="z" value="789"/>
    </a>
    <b>
        <item key="x" value="123"/>
        <item key="z" value="789"/>
    </b>
</root>
```

This stylesheet shows how to test equality, as defined in the question.

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0" xmlns:set="http://exslt.org/sets"  xmlns:exsl="http://exslt.org/common" 
 extension-element-prefixes="set exsl">
<xsl:output method="text" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"/> 

<xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:variable name="values-are-equal">
        <xsl:call-template name="equal">
            <xsl:with-param name="A" select="/root/a"/>
            <xsl:with-param name="B" select="/root/b"/>
        </xsl:call-template>
    </xsl:variable>
    <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="$values-are-equal = 1">Equal</xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise>Inequal</xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template name="equal">
    <xsl:param name="A" />
    <xsl:param name="B" />
    <xsl:variable name="common-keys" select="$A/item/@key[ count(set:distinct(  . | $B/item/@key )) = count( set:distinct( $B/item/@key ) ) ]"/>
    <xsl:variable name="differences">
        <xsl:for-each select="$common-keys">
            <xsl:if test="$A/item[@key = current()]/@value != $B/item[@key = current()]/@value">
                <different/>
            </xsl:if>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:variable>
    <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="count( exsl:node-set($differences)/* ) > 0">0</xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise>1</xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

This uses some extensions, which are available in xsltproc and other processors.

Comment: It isn't necessary to use any extensions and a simpler/shorter solution exists -- see my answer.