# XSLT: Transform nodes by comparing their child nodes

Tags: xml, python-3.x, xslt

To start off, I'm aware of this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14411425/xsl-comparing-nodes-by-comparing-their-child-nodes) which is a bit different.

I have an XML file which looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Document xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="urn:iso:std:iso:20022:tech:xsd:pain.001.001.03">
    <CstmrCdtTrfInitn>
        <GrpHdr>
            <MsgId>123</MsgId>
            <CreDtTm>321</CreDtTm>
            <NbOfTxs>10</NbOfTxs>
            <CtrlSum>18700.68</CtrlSum>
            <InitgPty>
                <Nm>some info</Nm>
            </InitgPty>
        </GrpHdr>

        <PmtInf>
            <!-- start -->
            <PmtInfId>asd</PmtInfId>
            <PmtMtd>TRF</PmtMtd>
            <BtchBookg>false</BtchBookg>
            <PmtTpInf>
                <InstrPrty>NORM</InstrPrty>
                <SvcLvl>
                    <Prtry>test</Prtry>
                </SvcLvl>
            </PmtTpInf>
            <ReqdExctnDt>date</ReqdExctnDt>
            <Dbtr>
                <Nm>something</Nm>
                <PstlAdr>
                    <AdrLine>addr 1</AdrLine>
                </PstlAdr>
            </Dbtr>
            <!-- end -->

            <CdtTrfTxInf>
                <PmtId>
                    <InstrId>16082672122</InstrId>
                    <EndToEndId>16082672122</EndToEndId>
                </PmtId>
                <Amt>
                    <InstdAmt Ccy="RON">2159.41</InstdAmt>
                </Amt>
                <CdtrAgt>
                    <FinInstnId>
                        <BIC>some bic</BIC>
                    </FinInstnId>
                </CdtrAgt>
            </CdtTrfTxInf>
        </PmtInf>

        <PmtInf>
            <!-- start -->
            <PmtInfId>asd</PmtInfId>
            <PmtMtd>TRF</PmtMtd>
            <BtchBookg>false</BtchBookg>
            <PmtTpInf>
                <InstrPrty>NORM</InstrPrty>
                <SvcLvl>
                    <Prtry>test</Prtry>
                </SvcLvl>
            </PmtTpInf>
            <ReqdExctnDt>date</ReqdExctnDt>
            <Dbtr>
                <Nm>something</Nm>
                <PstlAdr>
                    <AdrLine>addr 1</AdrLine>
                </PstlAdr>
            </Dbtr>
            <!-- end -->

            <CdtTrfTxInf>
                <PmtId>
                    <InstrId>16082672122</InstrId>
                    <EndToEndId>16082672122</EndToEndId>
                </PmtId>
                <Amt>
                    <InstdAmt Ccy="RON">2159.41</InstdAmt>
                </Amt>
                <CdtrAgt>
                    <FinInstnId>
                        <BIC>some bic</BIC>
                    </FinInstnId>
                </CdtrAgt>
            </CdtTrfTxInf>
        </PmtInf>

        <PmtInf>
            <!-- start -->
            <PmtInfId>asd</PmtInfId>
            <PmtMtd>TRF</PmtMtd>
            <BtchBookg>false</BtchBookg>
            <PmtTpInf>
                <InstrPrty>NORM</InstrPrty>
                <SvcLvl>
                    <Prtry>test</Prtry>
                </SvcLvl>
            </PmtTpInf>
            <ReqdExctnDt>date</ReqdExctnDt>
            <Dbtr>
                <Nm>something</Nm>
                <PstlAdr>
                    <AdrLine>addr 1</AdrLine>
                </PstlAdr>
            </Dbtr>
            <!-- end -->

            <CdtTrfTxInf>
                <PmtId>
                    <InstrId>16082672122</InstrId>
                    <EndToEndId>16082672122</EndToEndId>
                </PmtId>
                <Amt>
                    <InstdAmt Ccy="RON">2159.41</InstdAmt>
                </Amt>
                <CdtrAgt>
                    <FinInstnId>
                        <BIC>some bic</BIC>
                    </FinInstnId>
                </CdtrAgt>
            </CdtTrfTxInf>
        </PmtInf>

        <PmtInf>
            <!-- start -->
            <PmtInfId>asd</PmtInfId>
            <PmtMtd>TRF</PmtMtd>
            <BtchBookg>false</BtchBookg>
            <PmtTpInf>
                <InstrPrty>NORM</InstrPrty>
                <SvcLvl>
                    <Prtry>test</Prtry>
                </SvcLvl>
            </PmtTpInf>
            <ReqdExctnDt>date</ReqdExctnDt>
            <Dbtr>
                <Nm>something</Nm>
                <PstlAdr>
                    <AdrLine>addr 1</AdrLine>
                </PstlAdr>
            </Dbtr>
            <!-- end -->

            <CdtTrfTxInf>
                <PmtId>
                    <InstrId>16082672122</InstrId>
                    <EndToEndId>16082672122</EndToEndId>
                </PmtId>
                <Amt>
                    <InstdAmt Ccy="RON">2159.41</InstdAmt>
                </Amt>
                <CdtrAgt>
                    <FinInstnId>
                        <BIC>some bic</BIC>
                    </FinInstnId>
                </CdtrAgt>
            </CdtTrfTxInf>
        </PmtInf>
    </CstmrCdtTrfInitn>
</Document>
```

- as you can see, I have multiple (4) `<PmtInf></PmtInf>` sections which have *almost* the same structure.
- what I'd like to do, is:

  1. compare `<PmtInfId>asd</PmtInfId>` from the first `PmtInf` with `<PmtInfId>asd</PmtInfId>` from the second `PmtInf`. If there's a perfect match(as in the same tag and text), move to the next tag elements and compare them (`<PmtMtd>TRF</PmtMtd>` from the first `PmtInf` with `<PmtMtd>TRF</PmtMtd>` from the second `PmtInf`... and if there's always a perfect match do so until we reach the `<CdtTrfTxInf>` tag.
  2. when we reached `<CdtTrfTxInf>`, it means the first part of the first `PmtInf` is the same as the first part of the second `PmtInf`. At this point, move `<CdtTrfTxInf></CdtTrfTxInf>` from the second `PmtInf` right after the `<CdtTrfTxInf></CdtTrfTxInf>` section from the first `PmtInf`. Then, remove the second `PmtInf` section.

So, at this moment, the xml would look like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Document xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="urn:iso:std:iso:20022:tech:xsd:pain.001.001.03">
    <CstmrCdtTrfInitn>
        <GrpHdr>
            <MsgId>123</MsgId>
            <CreDtTm>321</CreDtTm>
            <NbOfTxs>10</NbOfTxs>
            <CtrlSum>18700.68</CtrlSum>
            <InitgPty>
                <Nm>some info</Nm>
            </InitgPty>
        </GrpHdr>

        <PmtInf>
            <!-- start -->
            <PmtInfId>asd</PmtInfId>
            <PmtMtd>TRF</PmtMtd>
            <BtchBookg>false</BtchBookg>
            <PmtTpInf>
                <InstrPrty>NORM</InstrPrty>
                <SvcLvl>
                    <Prtry>test</Prtry>
                </SvcLvl>
            </PmtTpInf>
            <ReqdExctnDt>date</ReqdExctnDt>
            <Dbtr>
                <Nm>something</Nm>
                <PstlAdr>
                    <AdrLine>addr 1</AdrLine>
                </PstlAdr>
            </Dbtr>
            <!-- end -->

            <CdtTrfTxInf>
                <PmtId>
                    <InstrId>16082672122</InstrId>
                    <EndToEndId>16082672122</EndToEndId>
                </PmtId>
                <Amt>
                    <InstdAmt Ccy="RON">2159.41</InstdAmt>
                </Amt>
                <CdtrAgt>
                    <FinInstnId>
                        <BIC>some bic</BIC>
                    </FinInstnId>
                </CdtrAgt>
            </CdtTrfTxInf>

            <CdtTrfTxInf>
                <PmtId>
                    <InstrId>16082672122</InstrId>
                    <EndToEndId>16082672122</EndToEndId>
                </PmtId>
                <Amt>
                    <InstdAmt Ccy="RON">2159.41</InstdAmt>
                </Amt>
                <CdtrAgt>
                    <FinInstnId>
                        <BIC>some bic</BIC>
                    </FinInstnId>
                </CdtrAgt>
            </CdtTrfTxInf>


        </PmtInf>

        <PmtInf>
            <!-- start -->
            <PmtInfId>qwe</PmtInfId>
            <PmtMtd>TRF</PmtMtd>
            <BtchBookg>false</BtchBookg>
            <PmtTpInf>
                <InstrPrty>HIGH</InstrPrty>
                <SvcLvl>
                    <Prtry>test</Prtry>
                </SvcLvl>
            </PmtTpInf>
            <ReqdExctnDt>date</ReqdExctnDt>
            <Dbtr>
                <Nm>something</Nm>
                <PstlAdr>
                    <AdrLine>addr 1</AdrLine>
                </PstlAdr>
            </Dbtr>
            <!-- end -->

            <CdtTrfTxInf>
                <PmtId>
                    <InstrId>16082672122</InstrId>
                    <EndToEndId>16082672122</EndToEndId>
                </PmtId>
                <Amt>
                    <InstdAmt Ccy="RON">2159.41</InstdAmt>
                </Amt>
                <CdtrAgt>
                    <FinInstnId>
                        <BIC>some bic</BIC>
                    </FinInstnId>
                </CdtrAgt>
            </CdtTrfTxInf>
        </PmtInf>

        <PmtInf>
            <!-- start -->
            <PmtInfId>asd</PmtInfId>
            <PmtMtd>TRF</PmtMtd>
            <BtchBookg>false</BtchBookg>
            <PmtTpInf>
                <InstrPrty>NORM</InstrPrty>
                <SvcLvl>
                    <Prtry>test</Prtry>
                </SvcLvl>
            </PmtTpInf>
            <ReqdExctnDt>date</ReqdExctnDt>
            <Dbtr>
                <Nm>something</Nm>
                <PstlAdr>
                    <AdrLine>addr 1</AdrLine>
                </PstlAdr>
            </Dbtr>
            <!-- end -->

            <CdtTrfTxInf>
                <PmtId>
                    <InstrId>16082672122</InstrId>
                    <EndToEndId>16082672122</EndToEndId>
                </PmtId>
                <Amt>
                    <InstdAmt Ccy="RON">2159.41</InstdAmt>
                </Amt>
                <CdtrAgt>
                    <FinInstnId>
                        <BIC>some bic</BIC>
                    </FinInstnId>
                </CdtrAgt>
            </CdtTrfTxInf>
        </PmtInf>
    </CstmrCdtTrfInitn>
</Document>
```

3. now repeat the process with the first `PmtInf` section and the third one and then with the forth one. If there are almost perfect matches, we should only have one `PmtInf` tag with 4 `CdtTrfTxInf` tags inside it.
4. if, at some point, there's a mismatch (say, when comparing `<InstrPrty>NORM</InstrPrty>` from the first `PmtInf` with `<InstrPrty>HIGH</InstrPrty>` from the third `PmtInf`, leave that `PmtInf` section as it is and go to the next one.
5. after we finished to compare the first `PmtInf`s with all `PmtInfs` above it, compare the second `PmtInf` with the third one and apply the same rules, then the third one with the forth one...and so on.

Now I might ask too much, but can this be done with XSLT ? I know I didn't try a thing but I just spent too much on trying to achieve this with simple Python string manipulations and it looks like XSLT transformations docs require some time to get used with the syntax.

---

I'm calling the script like this:

```
def parse_xml(file, output_path):
    parser = ET.XMLParser(encoding='utf-8', recover=True)
    dom = ET.parse(file, parser=parser)
    xslt = ET.fromstring(TEMPLATE_XSLT)  # TEMPLATE_XSLT contains the transformation

    transform = ET.XSLT(xslt)
    new_dom = transform(dom)

    with open(output_path, 'wb') as xml_file:
        xml_file.write(new_dom)
```

Comment: Can you use XSLT 2.0? If yes, look at: https://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-functions/#func-deep-equal

Comment: Apparently, the `lxml` module from Python allows only v1.0 so I guess I have to hang with that. Do you have a bit of time to help me with this ? It looks like an awesome transformation language which I really don't fully get. Any explanations are welcome !

Comment: I am afraid that's quite an undertaking. Have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33610324/xslt-how-to-find-the-count-of-unique-children-of-a-node/33614575#33614575 for XSLT 1.0 implementation of deep-equal.

Comment: Yep, I saw that...but I guess I need a bit of guidance. At least, some sort of a pseudo-code to get me started.

Comment: Why do you say that the sections to be compared have **almost** the same structure? They all have exactly the same structure in the given example - and if that structure is constant, you could make the comparison by listing the nodes to be compared explicitly. It would be verbose, but easy.

Comment: @michael.hor257k I'm saying this because there might be other values inside that tags (it's true, in the given example, they're all the same). More, there might be another extra-tags here or there. By that, I mean that in the second `PmtInf` I can have after the `<Prtry>test</Prtry>` tag another one like `<other>124</other>`. If all the fields from the first and the second (or third etc) `PmtInf` are the same, but there's that extra tag, that would make them different.

Comment: Do you have a schema that they must follow, even if some items are optional? -- Note: Your use of *values* is confusing: we're not talking about the string-values of the nodes (elements or attributes), we're talking strictly about the XML structure. I would also presume that the order in which the elements appear is insignificant, so that could be another relaxing factor.

Comment: @michael.hor257k Well, there's no defined XML schema for this, but as far as I know we can assume that each child that also has at least one child might have more than one (e.g: `<PmtTpInf>` can have other childs than what is already there; `<SvcLvl>` can also have another child.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I hesitate whether to post this at all, because you seem to be a beginner at XSLT and this is a complex solution to a complex problem. It may take you quite some time to wrap your head around this.

How this works:

In the first pass, we generate a `pmt` element for each `PmtInf` element in your input XML, and populate it with a string that contains a name/value pair for each node (element or attribute) descendant of the current `PmtInf`. In the given example, each such `pmt` element would look similar to:

```
<pmt id="idp1696">[PmtInfId:asd][PmtMtd:TRF][BtchBookg:false][PmtTpInf:NORMtest][InstrPrty:NORM][SvcLvl:test][Prtry:test][ReqdExctnDt:date][Dbtr:somethingaddr 1][Nm:something][PstlAdr:addr 1][AdrLine:addr 1]</pmt>
```

In the next step we apply [Muenchian grouping](http://www.jenitennison.com/xslt/grouping/muenchian.html) to the `pmt` nodes generated in the first pass. For each distinct `pmt` node, we create a `PmtInf` element and populate it with:

1. the contents of the corresponding `PmtInf` element, except `CdtTrfTxInf` ;
2. a copy of  all `CdtTrfTxInf` elements from all the members of the group.

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns:ns0="urn:iso:std:iso:20022:tech:xsd:pain.001.001.03"
xmlns="urn:iso:std:iso:20022:tech:xsd:pain.001.001.03"
xmlns:exsl="http://exslt.org/common"
exclude-result-prefixes="ns0"
extension-element-prefixes="exsl">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<xsl:key name="pmt" match="ns0:pmt" use="." />
<xsl:key name="PmtInf" match="ns0:PmtInf" use="generate-id()" />

<xsl:variable name="input" select="/" />

<!-- identity transform -->
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="ns0:CstmrCdtTrfInitn">
    <!-- first pass -->
    <xsl:variable name="first-pass-rtf">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="ns0:PmtInf" mode="gen-key"/>
    </xsl:variable>
    <xsl:variable name="first-pass" select="exsl:node-set($first-pass-rtf)" />
    <!-- output -->
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:copy-of select="ns0:GrpHdr"/>
            <!-- for each distinct pmt -->
            <xsl:for-each select="$first-pass/ns0:pmt[count(. | key('pmt', .)[1]) = 1]">
                <xsl:variable name="id" select="@id" />
                <xsl:variable name="ids" select="key('pmt', .)/@id" />
                <PmtInf>
                    <!-- switch context back to XML input -->
                    <xsl:for-each select="$input">
                        <xsl:copy-of select="key('PmtInf', $id)/*[not(self::ns0:CdtTrfTxInf)]"/>
                        <xsl:copy-of select="key('PmtInf', $ids)/ns0:CdtTrfTxInf"/>
                    </xsl:for-each>
                </PmtInf>
            </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="ns0:PmtInf" mode="gen-key">
    <pmt id="{generate-id()}">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|*" mode="gen-key"/>
    </pmt>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="@*|node()" mode="gen-key">
    <xsl:text>[</xsl:text>
    <xsl:value-of select="name()"/>
    <xsl:text>:</xsl:text>
    <xsl:value-of select="."/>
    <xsl:text>]</xsl:text>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|*" mode="gen-key"/>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="ns0:CdtTrfTxInf" mode="gen-key"/>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: wow, that's amazing. It works! But this looks like a really advanced solution which I barely understand. It's awesome when you see how much you can do with `xsl`. Many thanks :)

Comment: one simple request I'd have in addition to this awesome solution. I just realized `<PmtInfId>asd</PmtInfId>` is always different for each `PmtInf` so I'd like to skip it when we do the comparison. Is this possible ? It would require a new question ?

Comment: I don't have time to test this now, but I believe that if you change `<xsl:template match="ns0:CdtTrfTxInf" mode="gen-key"/>` to `<xsl:template match="ns0:PmtInfId | ns0:CdtTrfTxInf" mode="gen-key"/>` it will exclude `PmtInfId` from the key computed for the purposes of evaluation - same as `CdtTrfTxInf` is excluded now.

Comment: thanks, it worked. Another issue that I face is that whenever a tag is empty(does not contain any information (e.g: `<tag></tag>`), this transformation removes the `<tag>` and leaves me only something like `<tag\>`. I'd rather prefer this not to happen. Is there a way of doing this ?

Comment: A self-closing `<tag/>` is semantically equivalent to an empty `<tag></tag>`. Why is this an issue?

Comment: it's not such a big deal. I was just curious for my own knowledge

Comment: It's not something you can control (at least not easily). If you change the output method to `html`, you won't get self-closing tags - but you might also get things you didn't ask for (e.g. a DOCTYPE declaration). I suggest you get used to `<tag/>` and don't worry about it.

Comment: you're right. I'll do so. Another thing that I've noticed is that after the transformation is done, at each end of line it's only adding `LF` instead of `CR LF` which unfortunately messes up all the formatting when I'm opening it with notepad. Any workaround for this ?

Comment: Not in XSLT but perhaps in Python, where you call the transformation?

Comment: I've added at the end of the question the part which is caling the `xslt` transformation part

Comment: I suggest you post this as a new question, as it has nothing to do with the specific problem discussed here. Make sure to include the `libxslt` tag.